# Load Assets Using a Gem (Having Troubles Won't Load Assets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I have a theme I'm constantly using on my sites. I've been trying to load css, js and plugin folder (included with the theme) assets through a gem.

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'phcthemes' with type 'application/javascript'
```

If I take out the javascript (css only) this doesn't execute and shows up exactly like this in compiled asset

```
*= phcthemes
```

My thoughts app wasn't recognizing the gem, I tried using isolate_namespace (commented out for now) also tried several different config using the info from answer below to no avail.

Main App application.css

```
*= phcthemes
```

Main App application.js

```
// require phcthemes
```

lib/phcthemers.rb

```
require "phcthemes/version"

module Phcthemes
    class MyRailtie < Rails::Railtie
    end

    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine

        # Isolate Namespace
        #isolate_namespace Phcthemes

        # Initialize Assets
        initializer :assets do |config|
            Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w{ application.js application.css }
            Rails.application.config.assets.paths << root.join("app", "assets", "javascripts")
            Rails.application.config.assets.paths << root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets")
        end

    end

end
```

phcthemes.gemspec

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)

# Maintain your gem's version:
require "phcthemes/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|

    spec.name        = "phcthemes"
    spec.version     = Phcthemes::VERSION
    spec.authors     = ["BradPotts"]
    spec.email       = ["bradley.j.potts@gmail.com"]
    spec.homepage    = "http://phcnetworks.net"
    spec.summary     = "PHCThemes"
    spec.description = "PHCNetworks theme with mtdevise and assets built in."
    spec.license     = "GPL-3.0"

    spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
    spec.bindir        = "exe"
    spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
    spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

    spec.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*", "LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.md"]

    # Main Structure & Security
    spec.add_dependency "rails", "~> 4.2.5.2"

    # Development & Testing
    spec.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"
    spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.11"
    spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
    spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 3.0"

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some code missing from your Engine class.
Include the following

```
initializer :assets do |config|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w{ myfile.js myfile.css }
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << root.join("app", "assets", "javascripts")
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets")
end
```

and then include your files in app/assets/javascripts or app/assets/stylesheets in your gem directory. I'd be surprised if it didn't work the same for the vendor directory or any other directory.

When the gem is installed to a Rails app, you'll still need to put require statements in application.css and application.js. By the way, your CSS requirement statement is incorrect - it should be `*= require phcthemes`

The [Railtie](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html) docs say that a Railtie class is needed when running initializers, so include the following class inside your main gem module:

```
class MyRailtie < Rails::Railtie
end
```

That should do it. You don't actually have to change the gemspec at all.

You can see my [socket_helpers](https://github.com/maxpleaner/socket_helpers) gem for an example. That's what I was building when I encountered this same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Max, it looks like it should work but doesn't with me for some reason. BTW thanks for the link to your project really helped me out. I updated my question with additional info and changes I made. Will keep working on this.

Comment: @bradpotts it looks like the css/js require statements in your question are still wrong, it should be `*= require phcthemes` and `//= require phxthemes`.  When there's no equal sign that means the dependency is not being loaded. The word 'require' after the equal sign is also necessary, both in CSS and JS

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I made the changes. I still have the same error, but I am satisfied as it seems correct and set me on the right direction. If you notice anything else please let me know.

Comment: Yes it is. Here's the link if you want to take a look at it. https://github.com/bradpotts/phc-themes

Comment: @bradpotts I forked your gem, fixed your problem, and made a pull request. See the comment on the pull request to learn what I did.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help me out, much appreciated I see all my newbie errors, this will also help me out next time I build something similar.

Comment: @maxpleaner, the OP's repo no longer exists.  Could you outline what you did for the pull-request you mention?  I am having multiple issues, one of which is pretty much this issue...

Here i have another related question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537357/rails-5-gemify-assets-manifest-file

Would you be able to let me know what I'm doing wrong?  My gem is here: https://github.com/jakehockey10/popcircle

Comment: @JakeSmith I don't remember what I did for the pull request, but I left a comment on your question