# Rails 5 "gemify" assets manifest file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines

### Update

Got this in a working state.  Gem can be found here: https://github.com/jakehockey10/popcircle

### Original post:

I am trying to "gemify" a jquery plugin as a learning experience.  The plugin I'm using also depends on `jquery.easing`, so in the gem's `vendor/assets/javascripts` folder, I have both `jquery.easing.js` as well as the other jquery plugin.

Here is what my gem's `<name_of_gem>.rb` file looks like:

```
require '<name_of_gem>/version'

module <NameOfGem>
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      initializer '<name_of_gem>.assets.precompile' do |app|
        app.config.assets.precompile += %w(
          big_round.png
          one.png
          two.png
          three.png
          four.png
          five.png
        )
      end
  end
end
```

Here is the current structure of the gem:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── console
│   └── setup
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── lib
│   ├── <name_of_gem>
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── <name_of_gem>.rb
├── LICENSE.txt
├── name_of_gem.gemspec
├── Rakefile
├── README.md
├── test
│   ├── <name_of_gem>_test.rb
│   └── test_helper.rb
└── vendor
└── assets
└── javascripts
├── jquery.easing.js
└── jquery.<name-of-gem>.js
```

When using the gem in a test app, I'd like to be able to just require the gem like `//= require <name-of-gem>` and have that be sufficient to have both of the javascripts files in the gem's vendor folder to be loaded into the test app's asset pipeline.  However, instead, I have to `//= require jquery.easing` and the other file individually in my test app.

Is there a way to have my gem bundle those assets up together and not have the developer of the app have to require both files individually?

Instead of this in my test app's `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery-easing.js
//= require jquery.<name-of-plugin>.js
```

I'd like to give the developers the opportunity to just say this in `application.js`:

```
//= require <name_of_gem>
```

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this except for concatenating the two javascript files in a build step

Comment: @maxpleaner, Thanks for your feedback.  I'll keep trying new things.  I'm having trouble including even assets that I have located in `app/assets/javascripts/` and `app/assets/stylesheets/`.  I just have a misunderstanding of the way these assets pull together when requested from the app using this engine as a gem.  I'd like to come up with something useful as my first gem, but this is much more difficult that I thought it was going to be.

Comment: @maxpleaner, and here is where I got the idea that I would like to have the developer only responsible for adding one mention in their local manifest files from this post: https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/design-for-including-rails-engine-assets-into-pipeline-manifest/

It's just old and I'm afraid I'm trying to do something that isn't done the same way anymore

Comment: that seems like a good tutorial, i'd try it first and the debug if it's not working.

Comment: @maxpleaner, what the dev tools were telling me was that I wasn't even getting the assets from the gem when installing it in a test app.  So I spent all that time trying to find the right set of changes across the few files that would make it work.